# Issue In Multistep form with progressbar using CSS3 and Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hiii Everyone,

I tried with multistep progressbar in my website.When i click next button it is working prefectly but in case of previous button content which is below of form overlap with multistep form.For example the text will be hidden back of form.For code

http://codepen.io/KavyaBabu17/pen/JKJbEO

HTML code

```
<!-- multistep form -->
<form id="msform">
  <!-- progressbar -->
  <ul id="progressbar">
    <li class="active">Account Setup</li>
    <li>Social Profiles</li>
    <li>Personal Details</li>
  </ul>
  <!-- fieldsets -->
  <fieldset>
    <h2 class="fs-title">Create your account</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">This is step 1</h3>
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
    <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" />
    <input type="password" name="cpass" placeholder="Confirm Password" />
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <h2 class="fs-title">Social Profiles</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Your presence on the social network</h3>
    <input type="text" name="twitter" placeholder="Twitter" />
    <input type="text" name="facebook" placeholder="Facebook" />
    <input type="text" name="gplus" placeholder="Google Plus" />
    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <h2 class="fs-title">Personal Details</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">We will never sell it</h3>
    <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" />
    <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" />
    <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" />
    <textarea name="address" placeholder="Address"></textarea>
    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Submit" />
  </fieldset>
</form>
<p>Traditional heading elements are designed to work best in the meat of your page content. When you need a heading to stand out, consider using a display heading—a larger, slightly more opinionated heading style.Traditional heading elements are designed
  to work best in the meat of your page content. When you need a heading to stand out, consider using a display heading—a larger, slightly more opinionated heading style.</p>
```

CSS

```
/*custom font*/

@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);

/*basic reset*/

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
  /*Image only BG fallback*/
  /*background = gradient + image pattern combo*/
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(196, 102, 0, 0.6), rgba(155, 89, 182, 0.6));
}

body {
  font-family: montserrat, arial, verdana;
}


/*form styles*/

#msform {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

#msform fieldset {
  background: white;
  border: 0 none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  padding: 20px 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 10%;
  /*stacking fieldsets above each other*/
  position: relative;
}


/*Hide all except first fieldset*/

#msform fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
  display: none;
}


/*inputs*/

#msform input,
#msform textarea {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: montserrat;
  color: #2C3E50;
  font-size: 13px;
}


/*buttons*/

#msform .action-button {
  width: 100px;
  background: #27AE60;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  border: 0 none;
  border-radius: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  margin: 10px 5px;
}

#msform .action-button:hover,
#msform .action-button:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white, 0 0 0 3px #27AE60;
}


/*headings*/

.fs-title {
  font-size: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #2C3E50;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.fs-subtitle {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #666;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}


/*progressbar*/

#progressbar {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  /*CSS counters to number the steps*/
  counter-reset: step;
}

#progressbar li {
  list-style-type: none;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 9px;
  width: 33.33%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

#progressbar li:before {
  content: counter(step);
  counter-increment: step;
  width: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #333;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 0 auto 5px auto;
}


/*progressbar connectors*/

#progressbar li:after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: -50%;
  top: 9px;
  z-index: -1;
  /*put it behind the numbers*/
}

#progressbar li:first-child:after {
  /*connector not needed before the first step*/
  content: none;
}


/*marking active/completed steps green*/


/*The number of the step and the connector before it = green*/

#progressbar li.active:before,
#progressbar li.active:after {
  background: #27AE60;
  color: white;
}
```

JS

```
//jQuery time
var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
var left, opacity, scale; //fieldset properties which we will animate
var animating; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches

$(".next").click(function() {
  if (animating) return false;
  animating = true;

  current_fs = $(this).parent();
  next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

  //activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
  $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

  //show the next fieldset
  next_fs.show();
  //hide the current fieldset with style
  current_fs.animate({
    opacity: 0
  }, {
    step: function(now, mx) {
      //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
      //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
      scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
      //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
      left = (now * 50) + "%";
      //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
      opacity = 1 - now;
      current_fs.css({
        'transform': 'scale(' + scale + ')',
        'position': 'absolute'
      });
      next_fs.css({
        'left': left,
        'opacity': opacity
      });
    },
    duration: 800,
    complete: function() {
      current_fs.hide();
      animating = false;
    },
    //this comes from the custom easing plugin
    easing: 'easeInOutBack'
  });
});

$(".previous").click(function() {
  if (animating) return false;
  animating = true;

  current_fs = $(this).parent();
  previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();

  //de-activate current step on progressbar
  $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");

  //show the previous fieldset
  previous_fs.show();
  //hide the current fieldset with style
  current_fs.animate({
    opacity: 0
  }, {
    step: function(now, mx) {
      //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
      //1. scale previous_fs from 80% to 100%
      scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
      //2. take current_fs to the right(50%) - from 0%
      left = ((1 - now) * 50) + "%";
      //3. increase opacity of previous_fs to 1 as it moves in
      opacity = 1 - now;
      current_fs.css({
        'left': left
      });
      previous_fs.css({
        'transform': 'scale(' + scale + ')',
        'opacity': opacity
      });
    },
    duration: 800,
    complete: function() {
      current_fs.hide();
      animating = false;
    },
    //this comes from the custom easing plugin
    easing: 'easeInOutBack'
  });
});

$(".submit").click(function() {
  return false;
})
```

I tried in so many ways and i fedup and i can't find single solution for this problem.If anyone help me tht will be great help for my project.Thanks in advance.Please bear my doubts I'm new to this environment.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps you.. Thanks 
I just added height to `#msform`

```js
//jQuery time
var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
var left, opacity, scale; //fieldset properties which we will animate
var animating; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches

$(".next").click(function() {
  if (animating) return false;
  animating = true;

  current_fs = $(this).parent();
  next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

  //activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
  $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

  //show the next fieldset
  next_fs.show();
  //hide the current fieldset with style
  current_fs.animate({
    opacity: 0
  }, {
    step: function(now, mx) {
      //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
      //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
      scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
      //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
      left = (now * 50) + "%";
      //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
      opacity = 1 - now;
      current_fs.css({
        'transform': 'scale(' + scale + ')',
        'position': 'absolute'
      });
      next_fs.css({
        'left': left,
        'opacity': opacity
      });
    },
    duration: 800,
    complete: function() {
      current_fs.hide();
      animating = false;
    },
    //this comes from the custom easing plugin
    easing: 'easeInOutBack'
  });
});

$(".previous").click(function() {
  if (animating) return false;
  animating = true;

  current_fs = $(this).parent();
  previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();

  //de-activate current step on progressbar
  $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");

  //show the previous fieldset
  previous_fs.show();
  //hide the current fieldset with style
  current_fs.animate({
    opacity: 0
  }, {
    step: function(now, mx) {
      //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
      //1. scale previous_fs from 80% to 100%
      scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
      //2. take current_fs to the right(50%) - from 0%
      left = ((1 - now) * 50) + "%";
      //3. increase opacity of previous_fs to 1 as it moves in
      opacity = 1 - now;
      current_fs.css({
        'left': left
      });
      previous_fs.css({
        'transform': 'scale(' + scale + ')',
        'opacity': opacity
      });
    },
    duration: 800,
    complete: function() {
      current_fs.hide();
      animating = false;
    },
    //this comes from the custom easing plugin
    easing: 'easeInOutBack'
  });
});

$(".submit").click(function() {
  return false;
})
```

```css
/*custom font*/

@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);

/*basic reset*/

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
  /*Image only BG fallback*/
  /*background = gradient + image pattern combo*/
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(196, 102, 0, 0.6), rgba(155, 89, 182, 0.6));
}

body {
  font-family: montserrat, arial, verdana;
}


/*form styles*/

#msform {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  height:440px;
}

#msform fieldset {
  background: white;
  border: 0 none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  padding: 20px 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 10%;
  /*stacking fieldsets above each other*/
  position: relative;
}


/*Hide all except first fieldset*/

#msform fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
  display: none;
}


/*inputs*/

#msform input,
#msform textarea {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: montserrat;
  color: #2C3E50;
  font-size: 13px;
}


/*buttons*/

#msform .action-button {
  width: 100px;
  background: #27AE60;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  border: 0 none;
  border-radius: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  margin: 10px 5px;
}

#msform .action-button:hover,
#msform .action-button:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white, 0 0 0 3px #27AE60;
}


/*headings*/

.fs-title {
  font-size: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #2C3E50;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.fs-subtitle {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #666;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}


/*progressbar*/

#progressbar {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  /*CSS counters to number the steps*/
  counter-reset: step;
}

#progressbar li {
  list-style-type: none;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 9px;
  width: 33.33%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

#progressbar li:before {
  content: counter(step);
  counter-increment: step;
  width: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #333;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 0 auto 5px auto;
}


/*progressbar connectors*/

#progressbar li:after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: -50%;
  top: 9px;
  z-index: -1;
  /*put it behind the numbers*/
}

#progressbar li:first-child:after {
  /*connector not needed before the first step*/
  content: none;
}


/*marking active/completed steps green*/


/*The number of the step and the connector before it = green*/

#progressbar li.active:before,
#progressbar li.active:after {
  background: #27AE60;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>


<!-- multistep form -->
<form id="msform">
  <!-- progressbar -->
  <ul id="progressbar">
    <li class="active">Account Setup</li>
    <li>Social Profiles</li>
    <li>Personal Details</li>
  </ul>
  <!-- fieldsets -->
  <fieldset>
    <h2 class="fs-title">Create your account</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">This is step 1</h3>
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
    <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" />
    <input type="password" name="cpass" placeholder="Confirm Password" />
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <h2 class="fs-title">Social Profiles</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Your presence on the social network</h3>
    <input type="text" name="twitter" placeholder="Twitter" />
    <input type="text" name="facebook" placeholder="Facebook" />
    <input type="text" name="gplus" placeholder="Google Plus" />
    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <h2 class="fs-title">Personal Details</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">We will never sell it</h3>
    <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" />
    <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" />
    <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" />
    <textarea name="address" placeholder="Address"></textarea>
    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Submit" />
  </fieldset>
</form>
<p>Traditional heading elements are designed to work best in the meat of your page content. When you need a heading to stand out, consider using a display heading—a larger, slightly more opinionated heading style.Traditional heading elements are designed
  to work best in the meat of your page content. When you need a heading to stand out, consider using a display heading—a larger, slightly more opinionated heading style.</p>
```

Comment: I tried like this also. But the issue i faced is.if step 1 has 5 textboxes and in step2 if i have 3 textboxes there will be a gap between two div.I couldnot set default height.Based on height of form it will take height of div if this possible

Comment: ya..got it..let me edit my answer with respect to your forms

Comment: I dont want to fix default height based on form expansion height will take automatically

Answer (score 0):

It is related **height CSS property**.Because the form section having position:absolute property.So we need to tell about height of this element before the element of text div.

Note: If you give position:absolute into any other div that will calculate Document window position in your browser.Hence,your code the text section(

tag) not consider the form position that's why overlapping the form section.

**Solution:** Set height to form element.